# i am not able to use ajax with javascript php output not showing

Tags: javascript, python, php, html, ajax

So my question is just simple why the code is not working.
I just want that inside div(with show id) should display the echo text written in php.
The same thing is working with txt file. But not with php or other.?

*ANOTHER QUESTION/DOUBT
CAN I USE PYTHON FILE INSTEAD OF PHP FILE?*

**HTML CODE HERE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>python with html</h2>
    <div id="show">
        
    </div>


    <script>
        let a = document.getElementById("show");
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("GET", "index.php", true);
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                            a.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                            
                        }
                    }

        xhr.send();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP CODE HERE**

```
<?php
echo "hi hello this is just a test text";

?>
```

I tried all possible test cases but it not showing the result with php file but the output is showing with text file.

Comment: _"CAN I USE PYTHON FILE INSTEAD OF PHP FILE?"_ - As long as your web server/environment supports Python, then sure...

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you checked for JS errors in the browser's developer console? Have you checked the network tab in the browser's developer tools to see if a request is being made and the response from the server? Are you even running this through a web server? If yes, does it have PHP support? Is the URL to `index.php` correct? Please add more details. You can read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better idea what is needed.

Comment: ok it was working in php file only not html file . How can i get the output of python file using ajax?

Comment: I have no idea, since I don't know anything about your environment. You need to research that subject and post a new question if you can't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Check in browser console, there is issue with CORS; (in case your are hosting boh of your pages onlytesting purpose put your html file in same directory where your index.php is placed, access it like localhost//file.html)